# Why does my SQL SELECT query output only 1 result

Tags: sql

The select function would sometumes output 1 result. Does anyone know why?

```sql
SELECT * FROM people 
WHERE id = (SELECT person_id FROM stars
            WHERE movie_id = (SELECT id FROM movies
                              WHERE year = 2004))
ORDER BY birth;
```

Comment: you shouldn't use subqueries if you want more than one result. I think you want a join

Comment: Try replacing `id =` with `id in`. Same with `movie_id`. Nevertheless bad style, you should be using joins.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: Got it to work by using a JOIN and replacing = with in

Comment: Will it work though without join if I only implement 'in' instead of =

Comment: `in` is perfectly fine. It is not bad style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid subqueries. You're best bet is to use something like the following code:

```
SELECT 
    ppl.* -- to get just people information
FROM 
    people ppl, 
    stars sta, 
    movies mov
WHERE 
    ppl.id = sta.person_id
    AND sta.movie_id = mov.id
    AND mov.YEAR = 2004
ORDER BY 
    ppl.birth;
```

If you want to have stars information or movie information you just need to add the desired fields on the return like `mov.title` (assuming you have a column named title on movies table :P)

**EDIT:**
As pointed out, I will leave an example using `JOIN` also.

```
SELECT 
    ppl.* -- to get just people information
FROM 
    people AS ppl
INNER JOIN
    stars AS sta ON ppl.id = sta.person_id
INNER JOIN
    movies AS mov ON sta.movie_id = mov.id
WHERE
    mov.YEAR = 2004;
```

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip :) You pointed out some good reasons to use explicit JOIN

Comment: You will not get any additional information this way. (Perhaps duplicate rows, depending on table data.)